# How to add (push) new items to a json array

Tags: arrays, json

I want to obtain the same array just like this:

```
var data = 
[
{"date":"20111001","Happy":"63.4","Sad":"62.7","Angry":"72.2"},    
{"date":"20111002","Happy":"67.4","Sad":"61.7","Angry":"52.2"},   
{"date":"20111003","Happy":"60.4","Sad":"84.7","Angry":"44.2"}
];
```

If I have two list: list items

```
var items=["date","Happy","Sad","Angry"];
```

and a values array:

```
    var values=[
            ["20111002","67.4","61.7","52.2"],
            ["20111003","60.4","84.7","44.2"],
        ];
```

How to combine to arrays: items and values in order to get the same first example?

Comment: Exactly how you do this will be language dependent, but you haven't specified which language you are using.

Comment: This question does not feature any JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var items = ["date","Happy","Sad","Angry"]; 
var values = [
    ["20111002","67.4","61.7","52.2"],
    ["20111003","60.4","84.7","44.2"],
];

var data = [],
    itemLen = items.length,
    i, len, j, item, o;

for (i = 0, len = values.length; i < len; ++i) {
    item = values[i];
    o = {};
    for (j = 0; j < itemLen; ++j) {
        o[items[j]] = item[j];
    }
    data.push(o);
}
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Minor point: you're redeclaring `i` and `len` in your `for` loop.

Comment: I use the same loop before but it didnt work but I forgot o = {}; thanks it works